# Adblock problem

Tags: adblock

I use adblock plus to remove annoying ads especially on cpasbien.pw (on firefox / ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit.)
The problem is when activating it, not only the ads are blocked, but also the download tab is hidden. So I can't download with adblock activated

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: That's not an Ubuntu issue, that's an adblock filters problem.  Have you considered adding an exemption rule for the specific elements you DON'T want to hide?

Comment: Not only is there no tab download, but I can perfectly click the big green "Download" button, using adblok plus. SO you're wrong. Twice.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly trivial to [detect somebody using adblock](https://thepcspy.com/read/how_to_block_adblock/) (disclaimer: mine) and by extension, either disable things on the page or make them not load in the first place. I would suggest that this site of yours is doing just that.

Your options are:

- Find the script (on their site) that's detecting ABP, find out how it's doing that and write a [userscript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to counteract their scripting.
- Find a different blocker (eg [µblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock/)) and see if that exhibits the same issues.
- Try full javascript blocking for that page (still detectable and may still cause issues) with something like [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/).
- Disable ABP for that site and live with the ads.
- Use another site.